# Implementing Facebook Login with Supabase

Tags: facebook, expo, supabase

I'm implementing Facebook login. [The Supabase official documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-facebook) seems to be out of date and I've had little luck with it.

Here's what I've done so far

- Create an app on Meta for Developers.
- Register `App ID`, `App secret` in Supabase
- Copy `Callback URL` in Supabase and paste it on `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` in Facebook Login Settings

After that, I've sent a login request on button click:

```js
await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
  provider: "facebook",
});
```

I was expecting to see the Facebook login UI appear, but nothing happens. I tried to print out the response and it shows:

```js
{"data": {"provider": "facebook", "url": "https://[secret].supabase.co/auth/v1/authorize?provider=facebook"}}, "error": null}
```

Am I implementing this incorrectly? I would appreciate some help on how to get the Facebook login UI to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supabase-js does not open the sign-in screen automatically unless the platform is the web. For Expo, you would have to manually open the returned URL on your own to complete the sign-in.

You also need to configure deep links to bring the user back to the app once they complete the sign-in.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/native-mobile-deep-linking

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I have completed getting the session information, but how do I proceed with the signup? Do I need to extract the required data from the session information and make an additional call to `supabase.auth.signUp`?

Comment: @n8o No need to call `supabase.auth.signUp` if you are using the OAuth login. Sign up and sign in is the same for OAuth login. If you have got the session information, that means you are signed in/ signed up.